# three.js boundto faceVertices

Tags: three.js, textures

I'm trying to assign values to vertices of a plane geometry. Each face must have it's own values for vertices. As I understand it, I have to use "boundTo" attribute, and it works fine if I bind it to faces or vertices. But I cannot get it working with boundTo faceVertices.
My code:

```
...
a_other_uv: {
    type: 'v2',
    boundTo: 'faceVertices',
    value: map.cellCover.getEmptyUVs()
},
...
```

To each face 2 textures are applied. This code works fine if boundTo faces or vertices.

Comment: What is "not working"? What does `getEmptyUVs()` return?

Comment: Ok, now it works if I use type: "v3"(albeit in a weird way), but if I use type: "v2" then this attribute complitly ignored. getEmptyUVs() returns an array of arrays (length of the first equals number of faces, second array contains THREE.Vector2).

Comment: Aha. Have a look at `setMeshBuffers()` in `WebGLRenderer.js` and if you search for `faceVertices` you will see that only `v3` and `v4` are supported. That needs to be fixed... But what is "weird" about `v3`? Can you please be more descriptive?

Comment: In my shaders I use vec2 type of variable, but was sending THREE.Vector3. if I send Vector2, then everything works fine, even though type in js script is set to "v3", but in shaders "vec2" and THREE.Vector2 are been sent.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are saying... Use `vec3` everywhere, and set the third component to zero. Does that wotk as expected?

Comment: No. I set attribute type "v3" and use vec2 and Vector2 everywere else, and that works fine...

Comment: Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, it does. vec2 is a WebGl type, v3 is just a value of an attribute "type" of a JavaScript object (var attributes = { type: "v2"... }), and THREE.Vector2, well, one can think of it as of an array of 2 numbers (var v = new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 1.7) ).

Comment: Hmmm. I will consider this closed, then.